# Why double.MaxValue is larger than long.MaxValue?

Tags: double

both of them hold 8 bytes, but how come the max value for double is *much* greater than the max value of long? there is a finite number of bits available, so how could you reach greater numbers with floating point variables?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses a different representation (floating point) using exponents and mantissa

For details see [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Answer (score 12):

A double has something called an exponent, which is basically just a scaling factor. This allows the range of double to be much greater, but at the cost of precision.

A long is a simple integer value with no scaling factor.

Answer (score 10):

[Floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) consist of a mantissa and an exponent, and the value of a floating point number is:

mantissa * 2<sup>exponent</sup>

The exponent in a Double is 11 bits, so the maximum value is of the magnitude 2<sup>2<sup>11 - 1</sup></sup> = 2<sup>1024</sup>, which is way more than the magnitude of a 64-bit signed double, which is 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

Answer (score 9):

Because floating-point representation is of lower precision.  While `long` type can represent *all* integer numbers in the range from its minimum to maximum, `double` type can only represent some of it.

Since they occupy same amount of bits, the amount of numbers each is capable to express are nearly equal (actually, `double` can represent fewer numbers).  Just the paces between these numbers are different.